# laravel admin org > z-song package >i force https by htaccess and after login to my admin panel redirect me to root

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, https, laravel-8, laravel-admin

i installed laravel 7 with laravel-admin.org 1.6 6 month ago.

then last month i upgrade it to laravel 8 and laravel-admin 1.8

in my local everything is ok

but in my server after config https with .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

when i go to /admin

after login with my admin credential admin panel redirect me to / root of my domainname.com

i dont know why please help me

```
    "php": "^7.3",
    "encore/laravel-admin": "^1.8",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "hekmatinasser/verta": "^1.10",
    "laravel-admin-ext/log-viewer": "^1.0",
    "laravel-admin-extensions/multi-language": "^0.0.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0.6",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
```

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: i did it but cant resolve it ... i reinstall it last night but error there

i test it in chrome incongnito and errors there

Answer (score 0):

after 5 hours chanllenging

i copy my whole project into root of my cpanel and then move my public folder into public_html

- i re-connect my cpanel to github again
- and then run **composer install** again
- and then move pure source into my public_html folder

all the things worked as well